# can't see the banner on my simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, admob

I want to add Admob in my app, the compilation is correct, but I can not see the banner on my simulator.
The app is for iPad in landscape mode.
I added the UUID of my macbook to the variable TEST_DEVICE_ID.

Could you help me ??

Thanks

```
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]
               initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                        self.view.frame.size.height -
                                        GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                        GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                        GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;

bannerView_.rootViewController = self;

[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];


[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,                                  
                       @"TEST_DEVICE_ID",                               
                       nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're not actually passing the request with testDevices to AdMob. To do that, you'll want to write:

```
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,                                  
                       @"TEST_DEVICE_ID",                               
                       nil];

[bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

Now when you actually release, you'll want to be able to get live ads too. To find out more information, implement [GADBannerViewDelegate](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#ios-gadbannerviewdelegate) and log why you aren't getting an ad:

```
- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view
    didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
  NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
}
```

Remember you'll need to add `bannerView_.delegate = self;` to set the delegate for this method to be fired.